# Can beef be frozen 3 days after purchase

Tags: food-safety, beef, ground-beef

The beef I bought was ground on the 8th. Is it safe to freeze on the 11th.

Answer (score 3):

The advice from the [Food Standards Agency](https://www.food.gov.uk/safety-hygiene/chilling#:%7E:text=A%20freezer%20acts%20as%20a,putting%20them%20in%20your%20freezer.) in the UK is that food can be frozen up to midnight on the use-by date on the packaging.  If you're still within that timeframe and the beef **has been stored properly** then you should be ok to freeze it.  If there's no use-by date on the packaging or the beef hasn't been  refrigerated since purchase then don't risk it.

Answer (score 1):

Freezing “stoops time” with regards to food safety. Therefore the question hinges on whether the beef is still safe **now**, which in turn depends on whether it’s

- packaged commercially with a specific gas mix
- or freshly ground at the butcher’s or at home?

The latter is certainly unsafe by now, for the former, check the label.